# How to make Rspec save_and_open_page automatically when any spec fails

Tags: rspec, capybara

I have...

**/spec/spec_helper.rb**:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/dsl'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fail_fast = true
  config.use_instantiated_fixtures = false 
  config.include(Capybara, :type => :integration)
end
```

So as soon as any spec fails, Rspec quits and shows you the error.

At the point, I'd like Rspec to also automatically call Capybara's `save_and_open_page` method. How can I do this?

[Capybara-Screenshot](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot) looks promising, but while it saves both the HTML and a screenshot as an image file (which I don't need), it does not automatically open them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the rspec's configuration you could define an after hook (https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks) for each example. It's not very well documented but the block for this hook could take an `example` param. On the `example` object you could test:

- is it a feature spec: `example.metadata[:type] == :feature`
- has it failed: `example.exception.present?`

The complete code snipped should look like:

```
  # RSpec 2
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.after do
      if example.metadata[:type] == :feature and example.exception.present?
        save_and_open_page
      end
    end
  end

  # RSpec 3
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.after do |example|
      if example.metadata[:type] == :feature and example.exception.present?
        save_and_open_page
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Rspec 3 requires to explicitly put `do |example|` for it to work

Comment: Weirdly enough using `around(:each)` with this same premise seems to open a blank page, while `after(:each)` opens the correct page. Thanks for the example code!

Answer (score 1):

In RSpec 2 in conjunction with Rails 4, I use this config block:

```
# In spec/spec_helper.rb or spec/support/name_it_as_you_wish.rb
#
# Automatically save and open the page
# whenever an expectation is not met in a features spec
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after(:each) do
    if example.metadata[:type] == :feature and example.exception.present?
      save_and_open_page
    end
  end
end
```